# FAQ on 'Reputation' might need an update

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, faq-update-request

Privileges on StackExchange come with Reputation. I noticed that some of the privileges (https://ux.stackexchange.com/privileges) are not listed in the FAQ section for Reputation (https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

**Missing in FAQ?**

- Talk in chat (20)
- Set bounties (75)
- Create a chat room (100)
- Established user (1000)
- Create tag synonyms (2500)

**Outdated in FAQ?**

- <s>Reduced advertising</s> (*depends on the StackExchange subsite*)

Comment: Why do you think the reduced ads part is outdated?

Comment: @Mat Maybe because it doesn't apply to [ux.se]. AFAIK only the trilogy sites have that privilege, because they have more advertisements to begin with.

Comment: @lunboks Right :-)

Comment: Ah, so maybe not outdated, but premature - assuming UX grows enough to "deserve" more adds :)

Answer (score 1):

I would rather not see "Established user" listed there. I'd much rather leave the "Show total up and down vote counts" that is already listed for 1,000 reputation. If people want to find out about the expanding user card, they can find it in the privileges pages, but I really don't see that one as important, that it needs to be listed there. Just putting "Established user" means absolutely nothing. What privileges, exactly, can I definitively see I gained from that text? Telling people they can now expand vote counts is much more important. It's a very commonly used feature that deserves attention. The expanding user card, eh, not so much. That's just one of those "extra" things that's kind of there but not really vital to the site in any way whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for bringing this up. I cannot reproduce the issue with the current build of our network sites. If the problem remains please let me know.

Comment: it is just obsolete... why are you answering it?